# Adding horizontal space between data on a Read only script

Tags: python, readfile

I need my output to look nice, and it looks very sloppy.

--------Current output---------

```
Below are the players and their scores

John Doe 120
Sally Smooth 115
```

----------End current output----------

My desired output follows

-------Desired output-----------------

```
Below are the players and their scores

John Doe         120
Sally Smooth     115
```

--------End desired output-------------

my current code follows;

```
def main():

     # opens the "golf.txt" file created in the Golf Player Input python
     # in read-only mode
     infile = open('golf.txt', 'r')

     print("Below are the players and their scores")
     print()

     # reads the player array from the file
     name = infile.readline()

     while name != '':

          # reads the score array from the file
          score = infile.readline()

          # strip newline from field
          name = name.rstrip('\n')
          score = score.rstrip('\n')
          # prints the names and scores
          print(name + " " + score)

          # read the name field of next record
          name = infile.readline()

     # closes the file    
     infile.close()


 main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tab character to format your spaces better.

```
print(name + "\t" + score)
```

This should give you something closer to your desired output. But you may need to use two if some names are long.

Comment: Below are the players and their scores

John Doe          120
Sally Smooth  115
>>>

Comment: As an after thought you may also want to try installing and using 'tabulate' which will give you a nicer output without needing to manually calculate name sizes. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the names and the scores to a list and then print it as a table as

```
import numpy as np
name_list = ['jane doe' ,'sally smooth']
score = np.array([[102,],[106,]]) #make a numpy array 
row_format ="{:>15}" * (len(name_list))
for name, row in zip(name_list, score):
    print(row_format.format(name, *row))
```

Note: This depends on str.format()

This code will output:

```
           jane doe            102
       sally smooth            106
```